# Installable package NOT in pypi

Tags: python, package, installation

Is there any way to make my library/package (in Python) installable without using pypi?
I would like to make my library installable, however, currently, I do not want to use pypi for that purpose.

I searched for that in Google, however, did not find any information on other ways.

Comment: can you elaborate what your goal is? you don't want to make package/wheel? You don't want to publish on PyPi? Something else?

Comment: The goal is to have my library installable without using pypi :)

Comment: one option is to install project/package directly from repo e.g. if you have your project on github. read https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support. Another option is to make wheel, host it anywhere and make user download it and install from the wheel locally

Comment: Thanks a lot @buran!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can have your package on a repo via GitHub or a similar service.

You could also make a conda package.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html#who-is-this-for